# Is file transfer possible with asmack?

Tags: android, openfire, smack, asmack

I am implementing a chat application ,for that i am using

1.**Openfire server**

2.**asmack-jse-buddycloud-2010.12.11.jar**

I am able to text chat. But now i am trying for **file transfer** .
I have tried almost all documents code, but nothing worked for me. **Some developers are writing that it is a asmack and smack bug.**

So, Has somebody implemented file transfer code using asmack . If it's not a asmack issue then please give me some suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, file transfer is possible with aSmack (and Smack). But it is not always successful. See:  https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/wiki/aSmack-XMPP-File-Transfer

Comment: Have you got any solution ?